# map to different document roots with single IP address in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a situation where I need to serve multiple websites from the same IP address for testing purposes with Apache. I need to set the sites up as follows:

```
  67.54.34.2/site1    ->    site1_folder
  67.54.34.2/site2    ->    site2_folder
  67.54.34.2/site3    ->    site3_folder
```

In other words, I want to append a folder name (or append something) to the IP address and map this to a document root. How can I set something like this up in Apache? Also, is it possible to set it up to automatically map to certain folders so I don't have to add directives for each documentRoot?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use vhosts ( virtual hosts )

There are very simple how-tos on the internet..

READ THIS.... :D

http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/1127571/Apache-Guide-Setting-Up-Virtual-Hosts.htm